# How to get Java Unflagged Key Inputs Like With Pyinterception?

Tags: python, java, input, key, interception

I'm trying to get unflagged key inputs like possible with: https://github.com/kennyhml/pyinterception, but for java. Currently I'm just using Robot but I was wondering if a library like that exists for java, or if I could use this somehow in java, or if there is any other way for this to be possible.

Thanks in advance.

I tried several java libraries but didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.